# JQuery or PHP Auto Stacking effect

Tags: php, jquery

I thought i've seen this effect plugin before: http://www.creativedepart.com/ but i did not save it.

Appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction. I'ld like to have my divs placed without spacings above and below regardless of their height. I tried float left but it seems to still have the spacings in between.

Comment: Looks like Javascript. However, you can accomplish similar effect by having a certain number of column divs and then just inserting those blocks inside them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done in javascript. Here's a [list of jQuery plugins doing this](http://smashfreakz.com/2013/04/jquery-pinterest-layout/).